# Rename or Replace the default "Close" button in an UNNotification

Tags: swift, macos

How do I rename, replace, or remove the "Close" button in the notification on Mac OS?

Here's my code to show the notification:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current();
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent();
let notificationId:String = "test_not";

content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Will activate soon", arguments: nil);
content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "In 11 seconds.", arguments: nil)
content.categoryIdentifier = "Category";
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default;

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationId, content: content, trigger: UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false));

let cancelAction = UNNotificationAction.init(identifier: "Cancel", title: "Cancel", options: UNNotificationActionOptions());
let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction.init(identifier: "Snooze", title: "Don't ask again today", options: UNNotificationActionOptions());
let disableAction = UNNotificationAction.init(identifier: "Disable", title: "Disable permanentely", options: UNNotificationActionOptions());


let categories = UNNotificationCategory.init(identifier: "Category", actions: [cancelAction, snoozeAction, disableAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: .customDismissAction)

center.setNotificationCategories([categories]);
center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil);
```

[image: UNNotification Image]

Comment: If there isn't an obvious way to do it it's probably not possible, and it's for the best. It could enable developers to create notifications that can't be dismissed, and that's annoying.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Clicking on one of the actions automatically dismisses the notification. "If there isn't an obvious way to do it it's probably not possible" -> This is particularly funny considering we're talking about Apple's documentation which is known to be awful

Comment: Just because an action dismisses the notification doesn't make it an acceptable way to dismiss the alert. What if all the actions do something and I just want the notification to go away?